# Passing a variable from a method to a button click event

Tags: c#

I want to be able to pass upperEncodedMsg into the text property of msgLabel at the bottom of my code.

```
namespace ProgrammingAssignmentDecoder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        public void Encode()
        {
            string message = Convert.ToString(messageTxt.Text);
            char[] encodeArray = message.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < encodeArray.Length; i++)
            {
                char letter = (encodeArray[i]);

                switch (letter)
                {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'A':
                        encodeArray[i] = 't';
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                    case 'B':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'u';
                         break;
                    case 'c':
                    case 'C':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'v';
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                    case 'D':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'w';
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                    case 'E':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'x';
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                    case 'F':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'y';
                        break;
                    case 'g':
                    case 'G':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'z';
                        break;
                    case 'h':
                    case 'H':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'a';
                        break;
                    case 'i':
                    case 'I':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'b';
                        break;
                    case 'j':
                    case 'J':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'c';
                        break;
                    case 'k':
                    case 'K':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'd';
                        break;
                    case 'l':
                    case 'L':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'e';
                        break;
                    case 'm':
                    case 'M':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'f';
                        break;
                    case 'n':
                    case 'N':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'g';
                        break;
                    case 'o':
                    case 'O':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'h';
                        break;
                    case 'p':
                    case 'P':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'i';
                        break;
                    case 'q':
                    case 'Q':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'j';
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                    case 'R':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'k';
                        break;
                    case 's':
                    case 'S':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'l';
                        break;
                    case 't':
                    case 'T':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'm';
                        break;
                    case 'u':
                    case 'U':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'n';
                        break;
                    case 'v':
                    case 'V':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'o';
                        break;
                    case 'w':
                    case 'W':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'p';
                        break;
                    case 'x':
                    case 'X':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'q';
                        break;
                    case 'y':
                    case 'Y':
                        encodeArray[i] = 'r';
                        break;
                    case 'z':
                    case 'Z':
                        encodeArray[i] = 's';
                        break;



                }




            }

        }

        static string upperEncoded(char[] encodeArray, string upperEncodedMsg)
        {
            string encodedMsg = new string(encodeArray);
            upperEncodedMsg = encodedMsg.ToUpper();
            return upperEncodedMsg;

        }



        private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messageTxt.Text = string.Empty;
            msgLabel.Text = string.Empty;
            processedMessageLabel.Text = "Processed Message: ";

        }

        private void encodeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Encode();

            if (messageTxt.TextLength == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no message to Encode");
            }
            else
            {
                processedMessageLabel.Text = "Encoded Message: ";
                msgLabel.Visible = true;
            }

            msgLabel.Text = upperEncodedMsg;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it says that upperEncodedMsg is not currently used in the current context

Comment: make upperEncodedMsg a global variable

Comment: @prizm1 - That is A) not possible (no globals in C#) B) bad advice

Comment: i meant an attribute ;) sry for unclearness

Comment: did I do something wrong inside of my upperEncoded method?

Comment: all fine @WesMincic, but you can declare a variable in the object like the methods also, you can set the visibility like: private string upperEncodedMsg in the class itself to have it available in all methods

Comment: so inside 'private string upperEncodedMsg' have 'return upperEncodedMsg' ?

Comment: @prizm1 sorry im just having a hard time figuring this out. I don't know how to ask

Comment: give me a moment i will provide an example

Comment: Tangent not directly relevant to your question, but you could make this code a lot cleaner by using a `Dictionary<char, char>` for your character mapping. Just declare it once above, then the body of your `for` loop becomes just `encodeArray[i] = my_encoding[encodeArray[i]]`. You can initialize the dictionary like `Dictionary<char, char> myEncoding = new Dictionary<char, char>(){ {'a':'t'}, {'b':'u'}, etc...}`, see this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Comment: You can also cut out a lot of duplication by using the `Char.ToLower` method, like `Char.ToLower(someChar)`

Comment: For me, I think the biggest area of concern here is the use of a long switch statement. Try looking at alternatives (I've proposed a mapping using `Dictionary<char, char>` but there are other ways).

Comment: @sr28 okay i like that idea. Will that handle both lower case and upper case characters that are typed into messageTxt textbox?

Comment: Yes, it's completely up to you how you setup your mapping in your dictionary. My answer below currently takes all lower case and upper case input letters and maps them to something in upper case e.g. both 'a' and 'A' map to 'T'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to keep your structure in tact, there are a few things that could be done in less characters and in less complicated ways, but as you are learning the language practice is the only thing that can improve your skills :) So well done.

```
namespace ProgrammingAssignmentDecoder
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string upperEncodedMsg = null;

    public void Encode()
    {
        string message = Convert.ToString(messageTxt.Text);
        char[] encodeArray = message.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < encodeArray.Length; i++)
        {
            char letter = (encodeArray[i]);

            switch (letter)
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    encodeArray[i] = 't';
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'u';
                     break;
                case 'c':
                case 'C':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'v';
                    break;
                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'w';
                    break;
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'x';
                    break;
                case 'f':
                case 'F':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'y';
                    break;
                case 'g':
                case 'G':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'z';
                    break;
                case 'h':
                case 'H':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'a';
                    break;
                case 'i':
                case 'I':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'b';
                    break;
                case 'j':
                case 'J':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'c';
                    break;
                case 'k':
                case 'K':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'd';
                    break;
                case 'l':
                case 'L':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'e';
                    break;
                case 'm':
                case 'M':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'f';
                    break;
                case 'n':
                case 'N':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'g';
                    break;
                case 'o':
                case 'O':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'h';
                    break;
                case 'p':
                case 'P':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'i';
                    break;
                case 'q':
                case 'Q':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'j';
                    break;
                case 'r':
                case 'R':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'k';
                    break;
                case 's':
                case 'S':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'l';
                    break;
                case 't':
                case 'T':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'm';
                    break;
                case 'u':
                case 'U':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'n';
                    break;
                case 'v':
                case 'V':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'o';
                    break;
                case 'w':
                case 'W':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'p';
                    break;
                case 'x':
                case 'X':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'q';
                    break;
                case 'y':
                case 'Y':
                    encodeArray[i] = 'r';
                    break;
                case 'z':
                case 'Z':
                    encodeArray[i] = 's';
                    break;
            }
        }
       foreach (char eachChar in encodeArray) {
           upperEncodedMsg += eachChar;
       }

    }

   public void upperEncoded()

   {
       if (upperEncodedMsg != null)
       { upperEncodedMsg = upperEncodedMsg.ToUpper(); }

   }



    private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        messageTxt.Text = string.Empty;
        msgLabel.Text = string.Empty;
        processedMessageLabel.Text = "Processed Message: ";

    }

    private void encodeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (messageTxt.TextLength == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is no message to Encode");
        }
        else
        {
            Encode();
            upperEncoded();
            processedMessageLabel.Text = "Encoded Message: ";
            msgLabel.Visible = true;
        }

        msgLabel.Text = upperEncodedMsg;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help this worked. I am just trying to get through this class and the professor is brutal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go down the route of creating a mapping using a `Dictionary<char, char>`(see [here for details on Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)) and simply lookup the key value in the dictionary for each char in encodeArray. It may also be better to use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than just a string to store your encoded message.

**Create Mapping**

```
//Add Dictionary at the top of the class along with upperEncodedMsg string.
private Dictionary<char, char> charMapping;
private StringBuilder upperEncodedMsg;

//Create mappings. Use uppercase values here and you won't need to use your 'upperEncoded' method. This bit can be done in your Form1 constructor.

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    charMapping = new Dictionary<char, char>();
    charMapping.Add('A', 'T');
    charMapping.Add('B', 'U');

    //more mappings...
}
```

You can then remove the big switch statement you have and replace it with the following:

```
public void Encode()
{
    upperEncodedMsg = new StringBuilder();
    string message = Convert.ToString(messageTxt.Text);
    char[] encodeArray = message.ToUpper().ToCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < encodeArray.Length; i++)
    {
        //Use the mappings created earlier to get the associated char.
        char outputLetter;
        charMapping.TryGetValue(encodeArray[i], out outputLetter);

        //Append letter to your upperEncodedMsg StringBuilder.          
        upperEncodedMsg.Append(outputLetter);
    }
}
```

In your button click, at the bottom you can then add:

```
private void encodeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code...

    msgLabel.Text = upperEncodedMsg.ToString();
}
```

The main benefit of doing it this way is that your mappings can be made available in other parts of your code. It also makes it easier to maintain and your mappings are loaded as soon as the form is, rather than waiting to call your encode method. A lookup of a Dictionary is also likely to be quicker than a large switch statement.